# Images in HTML emails are broken in Amazon workmail

Tags: html-email, amazon-workmail

I am using amazon free tier EC2 instance and installed every required packages like php, apache, mysql etc. and evrything is working perfect.

Now I need to send/receive HTML email from my application which is running in EC2 so I have created Amazon SES instance and verified my domain as well email address which I am using to send/receive email. And I also created amazon workmail instance so I can receive my emails over there.

Logo image of my site is linked in all html emails.

Now when I send email from my application to the user like signup, forgot password etc. everything is working good.

But when user sends email to my application like contact us, my email client(Amazon Workmail) showing broken image for same logo image which am using in signup email.

I have searched for that and got some solutions like clear caching, renaming logo image but unfortunately not working for me. My server is SSL enabled. is that can be the issue? But I couldn't get that it's working when emails are being opened in gmail, yahoo etc. So what what can be the issue with the amazon workmail?

Can anyone please help me? Thanks!

**Update:**

This is my code:

```
$uname = $name;
$to = $to_email;
$from = $from_email;
$subject = "Contact Request from " . $uname;

$content = "<html>
            <head>
            <meta name='viewport' content='width=device-width, initial-scale=1'>
            </head>

            <body style='margin:0px; font:Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;' bgcolor='#FFFFFF'>

            <!-- HEADER -->
            <table style='width: 100%; max-width:630px; margin-left:auto; margin-right:auto;' bgcolor='#008FD4'>
                <tr>
                    <td width='100%'>
            <div style='font-family:Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;max-width: 600px; margin: 0 auto;display: block;'>
            <table width='100%' bgcolor='#008FD4'>
                <tr>
                    <td><img width='130px' src='https://path/to/image' alt='image'></td>
                    <td align='right'><h2 style='margin:0;padding:0; color:#FFF;'></h2></td>
                </tr>
            </table>
            </div>
                </td>
            </tr>
            </table>
            <!-- /HEADER -->

            <!-- BODY -->
            <table style='width:100%; font-family:Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;'>
            <tr>
            <td style='display:block!important; max-width:630px!important; margin:0 auto!important; /* makes it centered */clear:both!important;' bgcolor='#FFFFFF'>
            <div style='padding:15px;max-width:600px;height:auto;margin:0 auto;display:block;background-color: #e2e7eb; '>
            <table>
            <tr>
            <td> 
            </h3>   <p style='padding:15px; background-color:#ECF8FF; margin-bottom: 15px;font-size:14px; margin:10px;'>
            Name: " . $uname . " <br /><br />
            Email Address: " . $from . " <br /><br />
            Message: " . $message . "<br /><br />
            </p>
            </td>
            </tr>
            </table>
            <h3>User Profile:</h3>
            <table>
            <tr>
            <td> 
            </h3>   <p style='padding:15px; background-color:#ECF8FF; margin-bottom: 15px;font-size:14px; margin:10px;'>
            First Name: " . $fname . " <br /><br />
            Last Name: " . $lname . " <br /><br />
            E-mail: " . $profile_email . " <br /><br />
            Phone Number: " . $phone . " <br /><br />
            Organization/Company Name: " . $company . " <br /><br />
            Designation/Title: " .  $designation . " <br /><br />
            Address: " .  $address . " <br /><br />
            City: " .  $city . " <br /><br />
            State/Province/Territory: " . $state . " <br /><br />
            Country: " . $country . " <br /><br />
            Zip code/Pin Code: " . $zip . " <br /><br />
            </p>
            </td>
            </tr>
            </table>
            </div>
            <div style='padding:1px 1px 1px 15px;height:auto;margin:0 auto;display:block;background-color: #008FD4;'>
            </div>
            </body>
            </html>";

//set header part for email
$headers = "From: $from" . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8' . "\r\n";

if( $ok  = mail($to, $subject, $content, $headers) ) {
    ---
}
```

All the variables used in above code like `$fname`, `$lname` are assigned with values provided in `contact us` form

Comment: just so i am clear, by embedding you mean literally embedding images into HTML and not linking the image to HTML right? If you are embedding then some email clients will not show the image. Its best to link the image to the HTML.

Comment: `<img width='130px' src='https://path/to/image' alt='image'>` I have used this code in my email.

Comment: Ok thats linking. Your question isnt making sense, why would poeple send back to your application? Also add in code or path for the image please.

Comment: I have a `contact us` form in which users will fill their data and send it to my application.

Comment: The please paste the code for the email you get from the form in your original post. Full code will be helpful

Comment: I have updated my question with code.

Comment: lets talk more in [chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/149982/discussion-between-dd77-and-syfer)

Comment: Did you manage to solve this?